# Custom LDAP Schema

Tags: ldap, openldap

I want to create a LDAP schema for my university.
I want to create three sub organization unit in people such as below.

Is it a true method?

```
ou=academic,ou=people,dc=abc,dc=edu,dc=tr
ou=administrativestaff,ou=people,dc=abc,dc=edu,dc=tr
ou=student,ou=people,dc=abc,dc=edu,dc=tr

dn: uid=123456 ou=academic,ou=people,dc=abc,dc=edu,dc=tr
cn: mycn
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: top
userPassword:{crypt}0.oUw/zI****
uid: 123456

dn: uid=654321 ou=student,ou=people,dc=abc,dc=edu,dc=tr
cn: mycn
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: top
userPassword:{crypt}0.oUw/zI****
uid: 654321
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that "*schema*" in context with LDAP has a special meaning:

> [RFC 4512](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4512.html#section-4)
>
> ```
>   The Directory Schema is a set of definitions and constraints
>   concerning the structure of the DIT, the possible ways entries are
>   named, the information that can be held in an entry, the
>   attributes used to represent that information and their
>   organization into hierarchies to facilitate search and retrieval
>   of the information and the ways in which values of attributes may
>   be matched in attribute value and matching rule assertions.
> ```

Your question appears about what's called the Directory Information Tree (DIT).

> ```
> § 2.1 The information held in the Directory
> is collectively known as the Directory Information Base (DIB).
> The DIB is composed of a set of entries organized
> hierarchically in a tree structure known as the Directory Information
> Tree (DIT); specifically, a tree where vertices are the entries.
> ```

From: https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Directory%20Information%20Tree

> The following is a graphical example of a DIT:

[image: DIT/DIT.png]

> In this example, the entry `"dc=example,dc=com"` is the naming context, and it has two immediate children, with DNs of `"ou=People,dc=example,dc=com"` and `"ou=Groups,dc=example,dc=com"`, respectively, and each of those entries has its own subordinate entries.
> There is no predefined limit to the maximum depth of a directory tree, and any entry can potentially have one or more subordinate entries. An entry that does not contain any subordinates is said to be a leaf entry, and any entry that has at least one subordinate entry is called a non-leaf entry.

What you're proposing for your DIT is a priori no better or worse than other ideas.

I'm slightly worried by the  `userPassword:{crypt}0.oUw/zI****`. That looks very much like the legacy crypt function was used for the  password hash.
Please configure and use a more secure password hashing algorithm if you can.